# Tangent in specific point without model fitting

Tags: modeling, differential-equations

I have a question about differential function.

When I have one database with x and y, how can I find the slope in specific point?

For example,

```
x = c(3935, 3992, 4079, 4100, 4156, 4169, 4197, 4217, 4246, 4262, 4280, 4287, 4313, 4328, 4334, 4352, 4371, 4377, 4397, 4408, 4416, 4430, 4444, 4461, 4467, 4483, 4496, 4510, 4523, 4531, 4542, 4559, 4574, 4579, 4595, 4613, 4631, 4637, 4657, 4673, 4691, 4713, 4726, 4751, 4784, 4801, 4850, 4883, 4939, 5082)
y = c(30.75, 30.81, 30.9, 30.92, 30.97, 30.98, 31, 31.02, 31.04, 31.05. 31.07, 31.07, 31.09, 31.1, 31.1, 31.11, 31.12, 31.13, 31.14, 31.15, 31.15, 31.16, 31.16, 31.17, 31.18, 31.18, 31.19, 31.2, 31.2, 31.21, 31.21, 31.22, 31.22, 31.22, 31.23, 31.24, 31.24, 31.24, 31.25, 31.26, 31.26, 31.27, 31.27, 31.28, 31.28, 31.29, 31.3, 31.3, 31.31, 31.33)
```

[image]

And I want to know the slope when x=4476.8 (it is average value of x).

I know that the best way is to fit the function of x with respect to y and then differentiate it.

However, I am asking this question because I want to know if there is a way to find the tangent of a specific point without fitting the model.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have to presume that the function is differentiable at that point, we cannot know this. And then, you can only obtain approximations.

For instance, you could take the two points $(x^1, y^1), (x^2, y^2)$ (the superscript is just an index, not a power), where $x^1, x^2$ satisfy $x^1 < x^2$, and are the two points nearest to $x=4476.8$, and then compute $d = \frac{y^2 - y^1}{x^2 - x^1}$.

Next, you could take several such pairs $((x^1_i, y^1_i), (x^2_i, y^2_i))$ near $x$, compute for each such pair a weight $w_i$ that is somehow decreasing with the increasing sum $|x^1_i - x| + |x^2_i - x|$ and then take the weighted mean of the belonging quotients:
$$
d = \sum_{i=1}^k w_i \frac{y^2_i - y^1_i}{x^2_i - x^1_i}.
$$

But maybe this already counts as "fitting a model"...